# Emacs Dired: copying to the current folder

Tags: emacs

In Dired, copying is done like "copy the marked files to somewhere else". Is there a way to do this in the opposite direction?

That is, in the scenario I imagine I would get a question *what* to copy (path), and it would be copied / symlinked into the current directory. (In a "let's collect all the stuff that's needed to run a command in one place" way, for example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M-x copy-file RET will prompt for the source file, then default to the current directory. You could bind that to a key.

Or, if that's not good enough, let me know and I'll write the command and post it.

Eh, I had some time, so here's the command:

```
(defun dired-copy-file-here (file)
  (interactive "fCopy file: ")
  (copy-file file default-directory))
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(define-key dired-mode-map "\M-c" 'dired-copy-file-here))
```

Answer (score 2):

As Aurélien mentions, the only advantage you gain from being in a specific Dired buffer seems to be `.` means "here", so going for a shell `cp` is almost all you can do.

The other advantage that comes to my mind is, if you have *another* visible dired buffer (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>..), when you move/copy/link from the buffer you're in (from which you select all your files, therefore), emacs gives you some **default targets** as destinations, which are accessible with the `<down>` arrow when you're prompted in the minibuffer.

Say you have 2 dired buffers open, `~/here/` and `~/elsewhere/someplace/`, then selecting a few files in `~/here/`, pressing <kbd>C</kbd> in that buffer, then <kbd>↓</kbd> should give you the default option to copy stuff to `~/elsewhere/someplace/`. Same for single files, you get the default directory, and the default directory+filename (e.g. `~/here/some long annoying filename you'd like to edit.any` → `~/elsewhere/someplace/some long annoying filename you'd like to edit.any`).

Just press <kbd>↓</kbd> again for more defaults.

Comment: yours is not the answer I asked for but the answer I would have asked for if... I knew the answer... never mind, fact is that it seems to be a really good workflow! I also encountered the variable dired-dwim-target, for one less down arrow, might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
M-!
```

to execute a shell command and then

```
cp -r what_to_copy(path) ./
```